# Time complexity of an iteration algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I have an iteration algorithm, where at each iteration the amount of computation decrease gradually. Here is an illustration of my algorithm:

`Input size: n` and `Total iteration = k`

```
iter 1: time taken -> f1 * n
iter 2: time taken -> f2 * n
iter 3: time taken -> f3 * n
...
iter k: time taken -> fk * n
```

where `f1 > f2 > f3 >...> fk` and `0 <= f1, f2,...,fk <= 1`

Question: What is the time complexity of this algorithm? is it `Big-O(klog n)`

`Update:`

I think the question seems vague. I'll explain it in words:

Input for my algorithm is `n` and I'll run it over `k` iterations. but on each iteration the input size reduces by a factor which is `unknown`. there is no pattern in the reduction.

eg :

```
iter 1: input size = n (always n)
iter 2: input size = n/2 (can change)
iter 3: input size = n/5 (can change)
iter 4: input size = n/8 (can change)
...
iter k: input size = n/10 (can change)
```

Comment: no, I am trying to improve the 'farthest point selection' algorithm (Teofilo F. GONZALEZ (1985)), which has the time complexity of `Big-O (kn)`

Comment: Question: Do the fi's depend on n or k?

Comment: fi depends on `n`. I have added more information to the question. thank you.

Comment: Are the denominators always integers, or can they be reals?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13934/discussion-between-michael-graczyk-and-mahin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

More specifically:

If the denominators of your example:

```
iter 1: input size = n (always n)
iter 2: input size = n/2 (can change)
iter 3: input size = n/5 (can change)
iter 4: input size = n/8 (can change)
...
iter k: input size = n/10 (can change)
```

are strictly integers, then it is **O(n*log k )**.

Here's why.  For a sequence Xn to be **O(Yn)**, there must exists some M, a real number, and m, an integer, such that Xn < M*|Yn| for all n > m.

Now consider the sequence K = {1, 1/2, 1/3, ... 1/k}.  Also consider the sequence N = {1, 2, 3, 4...}.

Now let's let Yn = N^t * K (that's the outer left product of N and K).  This sequence Yn is always greater than your sequence, regardless of the values of the fi's.

So Xn < 1 * |Yn|, where Yn is the harmonic series times n.  As amit pointed out, Yn falls into **O(n*log k)**, so Xn does also.  Since we couldn't have bounded Xn any closer above, our best limiting approximation for Xn is also **O(n*log k)**.

Comment: fk is not constant, it matters a lot, if `f1,..., fk` has the zeno property? (consider `fk = 1/2^k`)

Comment: As long as they do not depend on k or n, it does not matter.

Comment: Why do you think they do not depend on `k`?  I do not see this constraint anywhere.

Comment: Lol no matter what it is in **O(k*n)**.  There might be a better limiting behavior (there isn't), but it's obviously in **O(k*n)**.

Comment: I think you would remove your doubt if you read the paper he cited :) https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~teo/papers/Ktmm.pdf

Comment: In your proof: we can't bound any tighter for the worst case of integer denominators since the partial sum of the harmonic sequence to `k` is greater than `log k`. But as amit said at the start, if `f_k` decreases rapidly enough then we might get a better bound. In the case where the sequence is `1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, ...` then the overall operation is `O(n)`. The questioner says that the improvement at each step is "unknown", but that might mean unknown to him rather than unknowable, so it might in fact be better than `O(n log k)`. As you say we can't prove better on the information given :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop I did some hand waving at the end because it's harder to type than to write proofs on paper.  However, the distinction between "unknown" and "unknowable" is immaterial here.  Why is that so?  The OP asked about a sequence 1/1, 1/f2, 1/f3.... 1/fk which is *non-random*.  They are not random variables, nor are they undetermined.  They are *unspecified*.  *Unspecified* parameters are not the same *unknown* parameters.  My proof is a proof given any f1, f2 ... fk where f1 > f2 > f3 >...> fk and 0 <= f1, f2,...,fk <= 1, because that's what was asked.  No more, *no less*.

Comment: Here's a clearer example of what I mean.  I want to show that the square of an even integer is even.  I say, **Let n be an even integer**. n can be written as 2*n... 4*n.... 4/2... blah blah QED.  After reading this proof you don't ask, "was n *unknown* or *unknowable*?"  It was neither.  It was *unspecified* because it can be any integer.  That is the power of relational logic, and that's why proofs work.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk: I have a degree in Maths, I don't need convincing of the power of logic :-) I was just outlining that a tighter bound might be possible given more information than has been provided. That's the only reason it's relevant whether the `f_k` values actually can be anything within the restrictions you assumed, or whether on closer examination it might turn out that there are better restrictions. Hopefully if the questioner has been holding back information (or not fully investigated the sequence), he now has a motive to explore further.

Answer (score 3):

The given information is not enough, all we can determine is that the complexity is **`O((f1+ ... + fk)*n)`**<sup>1</sup>.

**Why?** I'll show with an example, of two cases for `fi` - each giving different complexity:

**Case 1:**  `fi = 1/2^i`

In this case, we get `n * 1/2 + n* 1/4 + ... + n*1/2^k < n`, and the algorithm is `O(n)`

**Case 2:** `fi = 1/i`

In this case, we get a [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29): `n * 1/2 + n*1/3 + ... + n*1/k = n(1/2+1/3+...+1/k) = O(nlogk)`

**EDIT:**
based on your comments and edit, it seems that the worst case for the algorithm to run as described (if I understood you correctly) is:

```
iter1 -> n ops
iter2 -> n/2 ops
iter3 -> n/3 ops
...
iterk -> n/k ops
```

If this is indeed the case, it matches the described **case2**, the total run time is an [**harmonic series**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29): `n + n/2 + n/3 + .. + n/k = n(1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/k)`, which is **`O(nlogk)`**.

---

(1) Strictly mathematically speaking - big O is an upper asymptotic bound, and since `fi <= 1`, we can deduce the algorithm is `O(nk)`, but **it is NOT a strict bound**, as the examples show - different `fi` values can give different strict bounds.